# Intercept form submission, check submitted value and show easter egg

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".search-form").submit(function(e) {
    // if submitted value = "easter egg"
    //    e.preventDefault();
    //    show easter egg
    // else do nothing (let the form be submitted as usual)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="https://galina.xyz/" method="get" id="adminbarsearch">
  <input class="adminbar-input" name="s" id="adminbar-search" type="text" value="" maxlength="150" />
  <label for="adminbar-search" class="screen-reader-text">Search</label>
  <input type="submit" class="adminbar-button" value="Search" />
</form>
```

Could you help me organize this? I failed to find out the submitted value in 'e'.

Comment: We need to know the HTML too

Comment: What does your form look like? What are the input fields which are submitted?

Comment: I modified my question.

Comment: use document.getElementById("adminbar-input").value to get the entered value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In jQuery you're creating a `submit` function for `.search-form`, but in your HTML, there is no element with that class. You should create `submit` function for your form which has `id="adminbarsearch"`:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#adminbarsearch").submit(function(e) {
    if ($("#adminbar-search").val() === "easter egg")
    {
      // show easter egg
      console.log("Easter Egg");
    
      e.preventDefault();  
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="https://galina.xyz/" method="get" id="adminbarsearch">
  <label for="adminbar-search" class="screen-reader-text">Search</label>
  <input class="adminbar-input" name="s" id="adminbar-search" type="text" value="" maxlength="150" />
  <input type="submit" class="adminbar-button" value="Search" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't find it because your class selector is looking for `search-form`, but it is not set, so add it

e.g. `<form class="search-form"..`

Then use [Event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) in the listener to prevent the submission

e.g. `e.preventDefault();`

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".search-form").submit(function(e) {
    const searchVal = $(this).find('input[type=text]').val();
    if (searchVal == 'easter egg') {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log('surprise');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="search-form" action="https://galina.xyz/" method="get" id="adminbarsearch">
  <input class="adminbar-input" name="s" id="adminbar-search" type="text" value="" maxlength="150" />
  <label for="adminbar-search" class="screen-reader-text">Search</label>
  <input type="submit" class="adminbar-button" value="Search" />
</form>
```

Comment: OP asks for something to be done only when input is "easter egg", else the normal form submission should continue. Your code doesn't allow normal form submission for any input.

Comment: @kiner_shah ok I thought the question was mainly about why OP couldn't get element, but you are right, details are also very important, I adjusted my code, thank you for your reminder